# Windows Server 2008: Sometimes Windows shows the simple file sharing dialog while other times it shows the advanced dialog

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

when I try to share a folder to my LAN on Windows Server 2008 Standard by right clicking a folder and choose Share, sometimes Windows shows the simple file sharing dialog while other times it shows the advanced dialog. I have no idea why this happens, I want Windows to show the Simple file sharing dialog always. Can anyone help?

[image: Simple File Sharing Dialog]

[image: Advanced File Sharing Dialog]

Comment: I believe you get the simple file sharing dialog if you right-click a folder and choose share, whereas if you choose properties, and go to the share tab, you get the advanced sharing options.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, of course but I what I describe in my question happens when I right click a folder and choose Share. Sometimes it shows the simple dialog but other times the advanced one.

Comment: Weird. I have no clue then.